# How do I interpret this SQL error with alias name?

Tags: sql, vertica

I'm trying to run some code with a subquery but I'm not able to figure out why I'm getting an error.

```
select efile.*
from    
        (select can, 
        sum(case when tax_year = 2018 then IND_RETURNS_IN_SEASON+IND_RETURNS_EXT_SEASON else 0 end) as TY18_efiles,
        sum(case when tax_year = 2019 then IND_RETURNS_IN_SEASON+IND_RETURNS_EXT_SEASON else 0 end) as TY19_efiles
        from pcg_dm.ENT_AGG_CUST_MEASURES
        where can in 
                (select distinct can
                from pcg_dm.ENT_AGG_CUST_MEASURES
                where tax_year in (2019,2019)
                )
        group by 1
        order by 1
        limit 2000
        ) AS efile
join    
        (select can, st.STATE AS TY18_state
        from pcg_dm.ENT_AGG_CUST_ATTRIBUTES AS st
        where tax_year = 2018
        limit 2000
        )AS 18State
        
on
         efile.can=18state.can
```

I get the following error.

[Code: 4856, SQL State: 42601]  [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Syntax error at or near "18"

Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: “As 18State” - Is that valid syntax? Can table aliases have numbers in them? Try EighteenState

Comment: Thanks for the response- I tried that, but got the same issue [Code: 4856, SQL State: 42601]  [Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near "state"

Comment: Actually this worked thanks

Comment: Numbers are fine in alias as long as it doesn't start with it.

Answer (score 0):

You gave an alias name for the table in Line number 18 after the from clause. Try removing that and re-run the query.